# Using exceptions with Google Guava

Tags: java, exception, guava

What is the best pattern for using Google Guava with methods that should throw exceptions?

Let's say I have:

```
public Sting someMethod(Integer i) throws SomeException;
```

And I want to do:

```
List<String> s=Lists.transform(is,new Function<String, Integer>() {
       public String apply(Integer i) {
         return someMethod(i);
       }
     });
```

I couldn't do the above because of the exception.  Is there any nice pattern for handling it?

Comment: Use Java 8... Ha. Guava doesn't like checked exceptions.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How does Java 8 help?  The stream API doesn't seem to allow checked exceptions either.

Answer (score 8):

Propagate the checked exception as a RuntimeException:

```
try {
    return someMethod(i);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

EDIT: Since the transformed list is lazily evaluated, the exception won't be thrown until you access the list elements. You can force the evaluation by copying the transformed list into a new list, like:

```
s = new ArrayList<>(s);
```

You could wrap that in a try-catch block that catches RuntimeException and handles it however you want; your original SomeException instance can be obtained by calling getCause() on the RuntimeException. Or you could just let the RuntimeException bubble up.

Comment: What do I put outside my transform function?

Comment: If you're asking what kind of declaration you need on the transform method, then you don't need any at all. That's because a `RuntimeException` does not need to be declared to thrown. It will just be passed up the call stack until someone's interested.

Comment: Note that `Throwables::propagate(...)` has been deprecated as it was noted by Guava developers [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Why-we-deprecated-Throwables.propagate) so it's probably not that much different to catch the checked exception and then throw a wrapped `RuntimeException`

Comment: Thanks @DexterLegaspi -- I updated the answer to not use Throwables.propagate().

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public interface FunctionWithException<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    public R apply(T t) throws E;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you want to handle the exception.

1. Stop the list transformation when an exception occurs: See @dnault's answer.
2. Continue the list transformation and remove the element which caused exception (and log some error message).
   In this case, we will return null when an exception occurs, this null value will be removed from final list:

   ```
   List<String> s = Lists.newArrayList(
                   Iterables.filter(
                   Iterables.transform(l, new Function<Integer, String>() {
                   @Override
                      public String apply(Integer i) {
                        try {
                           return someMethod(i);
                       } catch (SomeException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                           return null;
                       }
                      }
        }), Predicates.notNull()))`
   ```

EDIT
If someMethod can return null value then you should a wrapper like this one:

```
class Wrapper {
    public Exception exception = null;
    public String result = null;
}
```

The list transformation will then be:

```
    List<Wrapper> wrappers = Lists.newArrayList(
            Iterables.filter(
            Iterables.transform(l, new Function<Integer, Wrapper>() {
               @Override
               public Wrapper apply(Integer i) {
                  Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
                  try {
                    wrapper.result = someMethod(i);
                  } catch (SomeException e) {
                    wrapper.exception = e;
                  }
                  return wrapper;
                }
             }), new Predicate<Wrapper>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(Wrapper wrapper) {
                    return wrapper.exception == null;
                }
            }));
```

Comment: I don't like using `null` as a sentinel, to be filtered out later. What happens when `someMethod` legitimately returns `null`? It's getting messy.

Comment: What do you think about wrapping the result?